# Using ActionCable to implement a sync room

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am trying without success to do something very simple: send a message to the client on subscription to a channel. My code:

## app/channels/products_channel.rb

```
class ProductsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribed
    stream_from "products:#{params[:id]}"
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "products:111", { price: 123, stock: 100 }
  end
end
```

And on the client side in my Vue app I do this:

```
...
   created: function(){
        this.channel = this.$root.cable.cable.subscriptions.create(
            'products:' + this.product_id, { // testing with 111
                connected: function() {
                    console.log("connected to channel");
                },
                subscribed: function(){
                    console.log("Subscribed")
                },
                disconnected: function() {
                    console.log("disconnected");
                },
                received: function(data) {
                    console.log('received');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        );
   } 
...
```

However nothing is happening. I can see the client sending the subscribe command and the channel identifier, but nothing beyond that point. In fact I don't even see "connected to channel" in the console, meaning the callback doesn't get fired.

What am I doing wrong?